# Angular 6 how to provide data as void array

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've done search which gets array and then filters the names of it on input. Everything works just fine if I write static :

```
export class AddComponent {
  protected dataService: CompleterData;
  protected searchData = [
    {name: '84A4DA'},
    {name: '846ASD'},
    {name: '8444AS'},
]
constructor(private completerService: CompleterService, private router: Router, public back: BackService,
             ) {
this.dataService = completerService.local(this.searchData, 'name', 'name');
}
```

But when I try to make my searchData from db firebase :

```
getArray(): void {
    this.afDatabase.list('/imones')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)//should give you the array of percentage.
        this.array = res;
      })
}

this.searchData = this.back.getArray();
  constructor(private completerService: CompleterService, private router: Router, public back: BackService,
             ) {
    this.dataService = completerService.local(this.searchData, 'name', 'name');
}
```

I get error :

[image]

**How to fix it ?**

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for this.?
And add the code for the `completerService` also

Comment: Completer service is ng2-completer module - not mine.

Comment: Return type for getArray() is of type void, and hence searchData is of type void, not an array. Rather write, this.searchData  = res; in the subscribe as that's where your array is.

Comment: how it should look ? searchdata = ??

Comment: I mean not when I change it to searchdata = res, but before, when I declare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, in the constructor, this.SearchData is NOT an array. The solucion is. 
1.-Your service must be return an observable. NOT subscribe in service
2.-Move your code from constructor to ngInit
3.-Is in subscribe function where you has the value of searchData

It's difficult understand your code for me, but, if your service return Observables -not data- I supouse your component can be like

```
constructor(private completerService: CompleterService, 
            private router: Router, public back: BackService){}
ngOnInit()
{
  this.back.getArray().subscribe(res=>{
      this.searchData=res;
      completerService.local(this.searchData, 'name', 'name').subscribe(res=>
      {
          this.dataService=res;
      });
  })
}

//Or , better, using switchMap
ngOnInit()
{
  this.back.getArray().pipe(switchMap(res=>{
      this.searchData=res;
      return completerService.local(this.searchData, 'name', 'name')
      }))
      .subscribe(res=>
      {
          this.dataService=res;
      });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did almost the same as first example, just I dont know why you subscribe the second  time, it's enaught to this.dataService = completerService.local.... Great explanation still.

Answer (score -1):

getArray() method does not return any array, but when you subscribe to your afDatabase.list, you get an array of values i assume, and hence in the subscribe callback, you should assign the value to your array.

```
getArray(): void {
this.afDatabase.list('/imones')
  .valueChanges()
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res)//should give you the array of percentage.
    this.searchData = res;
  })}
```

Or if you are getting values one by one, write

```
getArray(): void {
    this.afDatabase.list('/imones')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)//should give you the array of percentage.
        this.searchData.push(res); //searchData must be initialized as empty array
      })
}
```

Comment: This.searchdata then will be declared in service, how do I declare it before function ?

Comment: then return the observable from the service, and subscribe to it in the component.

Comment: I am trying :    this.searchData.push(res);, then this.back.searchData in that place, but still nothing, because it's an Object like : 0 {0, 1, 2, 3}

Comment: I mean, I think I dont get anything because there is 0 as first value, then there goes 0,1,2,3,4